# How can I display an image on webpage if it exists...else use "default image"?

Tags: php, html, file-exists

ok...this is my third attempt to try and solve this problem.  Hopefully I word it a little clearer this time around.  I have a folder containing various different images.

The folder name is: '../wp-content/gallery/playerphotos/'

The file name is passed through as:

```
$photoname = $row['First_Name'] . " " . $row['Last_Name'];
```

If the matching file exists, I would like to display the photo (".jpg").

If the file does not exist, then use the default photo in the same folder:
    '../wp-content/gallery/playerphotos/NoPhotoAvailable.jpg'

I look forward to hearing your suggestions.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: You could use the "file_exists" function http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Answer (score 2):

I have a trickier solution. Instead of having the (possibly minimal) overhead of calling `file_exists()` each time you want to serve a photo, just have PHP output the photo name as if it existed (Say for example: `../wp-content/gallery/playerphotos/Jack Sample.jpg`). Then write a little .htaccess rule (if you're using Apache) that sets the 404 file for the `playerphotos` directory to be `NoPhotoAvailable.jpg`. If you aren't using Apache, there are probably similar rules you can use for your server, but the advantage here is that while its not 100% portable, it hands the job of checking if the file exists to a program that is optimized to serve files. With apache you'd need a rule like this:

```
<Directory /path/to/www/wp-content/gallery/playerphotos>
    ErrorDocument 404 /wp-content/gallery/NoPhotoAvailable.jpg
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following PHP function to check if the file name (in your example, $photoname) exists:

```
bool file_exists ( string $filename )
```

Check out the documentation in the following page:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Comment: I finally figure out the problem It was related to the path I was using. I needed to define an absolute path:

    $absolutepath = $_SERVER{'DOCUMENT_ROOT'}.'wp-content/gallery/playerphotos/' . $photoname . '.jpg'; The file_exists function works fine now. ;)

Answer (score 1):

How about a little more tricky solution? :)

```
$photoname = (file_exists($row['First_Name']." ".$row['Last_Name']))?($row['First_Name']." ".$row['Last_Name']):("../wp-content/gallery/playerphotos/NoPhotoAvailable.jpg")
```

Then you just add an image tag

```
<img src="<?php echo $photoname; ?>" />
```

Comment: I finally figure out the problem It was related to the path I was using. I needed to define an absolute path: $absolutepath = $_SERVER{'DOCUMENT_ROOT'}.'wp-content/gallery/playerphotos/' . $photoname . '.jpg'; The file_exists function works fine now. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to use the PHP function file_exists which takes one argument as the file name.

You are going to want to first check to see if the file exists on the server. If it does not then set the photoname to the default name.

```
if(!file_exists($photoname)) {
    $photoname = '../wp-content/gallery/playerphotos/NoPhotoAvailable.jpg';
}
```